# historical stock data starting from 1900

Tags: stocks, history

Is there a source for very old historical stock data, starting from the 1900's? I am interested in this information for the purposes of personal historical research.

Gabe

Comment: I'm sure daily data exists for many stocks -- archives of the NY Times' financial section, for example. Whether any of it is in processable form, and at what level of detail -- and at what price -- would be the question.

Comment: Corporate action data is the issue from that timeframe.  i.e. Stock splits, spinoffs, mergers, stock dividends, cash dividends, symbol changes, company name changes.

Answer (score 3):

Robert Shiller published [US Stock Market data from 1871](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data.htm).  Ken French also has [historical data](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library.html) on his website.  Damodaran has a bunch of historical data, here is some [historical S&P data](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/New_Home_Page/datafile/histretSP.html).

Answer (score 1):

Good day!

Did a little research by using oldest public company (Dutch East India Company, VOC, traded in Amsterdam Stock Exchange) as search criteria and found this lovely graph from http://www.businessinsider.com/rise-and-fall-of-united-east-india-2013-11?IR=T :

[image]

Why it is relevant? Below the image I found the source of data - Global Financial Data. I guess the answer to your question would be to go there:

https://www.globalfinancialdata.com/index.html

Hope this helps and good luck in your search!